# what is map.ForEachFeatureAtPixel features order?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Does the ForEachFeatureAtPixel return the feature in zIndex draxw order? (top visible feature is the first returned by the method)

Thank you
David

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the order depends on the "inserted" order. There are many ways to add features to a layer. For example on a vector layer, you can use mylayer.addFeature (if i'm not mistaken), so when you call forEachFeatureAtPixel you will get "clicked" features ordered by their insertion order.  
If inserted A,B,C,D,E,F : you click on D and F, you will get [D, F]

Comment: Seem's legit :),

Comment: (too loog to edit my comment...) I forgot to mention that my feature are in different layers: layers A,B,C (in this order) and i hope that forEachFeature will serve the features in layers order.

Answer (score 1):

`Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel` drills down from top to bottom. So features rendered last are returned first. The same order applies for layers. Features from top layers are returned first, bottom last.